# Error when creating invisible.vbs on the fly?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

When I use a batch file to create the file `invisible.vbs`, then delete, it stops with an error. Basically, what I want to do is to have the batch file make this file.

This is the error that I get when I run the batch file:

```
C:\Users\HP\Desktop>"New Text Document.bat"
 CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """"
'WScript.Arguments' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
'""""' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

This is what's in the batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF  
CD /D %~dp0  
ECHO\ CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0,False>>Invisible.vbs  
::What I want to do with the file is here  
DEL %CD%\invisible.vbs /Q /S
```

I notice that the file is generated, but it is empty, and therefore does nothing when I try to use it to make another batch file invisible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the `&` symbol in your echo statement.  It needs to be escaped by the batch escape character `^` when using it literally `^&`.  You may also want to use the single output redirection operator `>` (overwrite existing) instead of the double `>>` (append to existing).

```
@ECHO OFF
CD /D %~dp0
ECHO.CreateObject^("Wscript.Shell"^).Run """" ^& WScript.Arguments^(0^) ^& """", 0,False>Invisible.vbs
::What I want to do with the file is here  
DEL %CD%\invisible.vbs /Q /S
```

Another tip would be to use the `%TEMP%` directory variable when creating throw away files.

Comment: Okay, this works, but now it says: `.Run was unexpected at this time`. What now?

Comment: @JeffreyLin When you see a message where it says 'blah' was unexpected at this time, just look at the character immediately before the 'blah' and you will find the cause.  In batch, parentheses `()` are special characters and they themselves should be escaped `^(^)` when used literally and not contained within quotations. Sorry I missed that.  Updated the answer.  Thankfully, this type of error does not cause a execution problem when redirecting echo output to a file.  Its just annoying.

Comment: @JeffreyLin In batch, parentheses `()` are special characters for (specifying scope) Note that there are many **annoyances** with batch and using special characters literally.  Batch special characters include `%&()^~<>` and note that some special characters do different things when following another special character.